# How to create keypress simulation program?

Tags: java, interface, interactive

## Main Problem

I'm trying to create a widely applicable keypress simulation program, but I don't know how to use Java so I can only search for Q&As on the site, which is inefficient. So I want to open a new post and deal with these problems all in once:

I need the following functionality:

1. Press arbitrary keys (using key codes shown [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html)) for example, some code like `press[65]` should press A.
2. Press arbitrary mouse keys (including mouse down, mouse up and mouse click)
3. Move mouse to a specific location
4. rotate the scrolling of the mouse
5. Screen shot

How to do these small functionalities? Thanks!

---

## Some work I've done

One can use these as a reference:

`JLink` part:

```
Needs["JLink`"];
ReinstallJava[];

robotclass = JavaNew["java.awt.Robot"];
LoadJavaClass["java.awt.event.InputEvent"];

move[{x_, y_}] := robotclass@mouseMove[x, y];
mouseleftdown[] := robotclass@mousePress[InputEvent`BUTTON1UMASK];
mouseleftup[] := robotclass@mouseRelease[InputEvent`BUTTON1UMASK];
mouseleftclick[] := CompoundExpression[mouseleftdown[], mouseleftup[]];
mouseleftdoubleclick[] := Do[mouseleftclick[], 2];
```

Mathematica Part:

```
MousePosition[];
CurrentValue[{"MouseButtonTest",1}]
```

---

## Related

[move cursor](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9332/programmatically-move-the-cursor-to-a-desired-location-on-the-screen)

[left mouse clicks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30695/automate-mouse-clicks-with-mathematica)

[key press](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32976/raise-systemwide-keypress-event/33004#33004)

[screen shots](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9331/take-screenshot-of-the-entire-desktop-using-mathematica)

Comment: related: [search?q=robotClass](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=robotClass) and [search?q=screenshot](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=screenshot)

Comment: What, that can't be found above, is missing?

Comment: What's missing?

Comment: What answers have you failed to find?

Comment: rotate scrolling and press arbitrary mouse keys (except left mouse button). but just willing to merge them together so that further readers can get a full image of how to manipulate such things with this post.

Comment: @Kuba up to now no Q&A include the content about scrolling or right key clicks. and unfortunately, simple alternation in the code apply for left nouse click will not work......

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A summary to all the stuffs:

```
Needs["JLink`"];
ReinstallJava[];

robotclass = JavaNew["java.awt.Robot"];
LoadJavaClass["java.awt.event.InputEvent"];
LoadJavaClass["java.awt.event.KeyEvent"];
LoadJavaClass["java.awt.Event"];

(*Action*)
mousemove[{x_, y_}] := robotclass@mouseMove[x, y];

leftmousedown[] := robotclass@mousePress[InputEvent`BUTTON1UMASK];
leftmouseup[] := robotclass@mouseRelease[InputEvent`BUTTON1UMASK];
rightmousedown[] := robotclass@mousePress[InputEvent`BUTTON3UMASK];
rightmouseup[] := robotclass@mouseRelease[InputEvent`BUTTON3UMASK];
midmousedown[] := robotclass@mousePress[InputEvent`BUTTON2UMASK];
midmouseup[] := robotclass@mouseRelease[InputEvent`BUTTON2UMASK];
leftmouseclick[t_: 1] := 
  Do[CompoundExpression[leftmousedown[], leftmouseup[]], t];
rightmouseclick[] := 
  CompoundExpression[rightmousedown[], rightmouseup[]];
midmouseclick[] := CompoundExpression[midmousedown[], midmouseup[]];

scroll[x_] := robotclass@mouseWheel@x;

keypress = (Function[k, 
      robotclass[keyPress[Symbol["KeyEvent`VKU" <> k]]]] /@ {##};
    Function[k, 
      robotclass[keyRelease[Symbol["KeyEvent`VKU" <> k]]]] /@ {##}) &;

(*Sense*)
getpixelcolor[{x_, y_}] := 
  StringCases[robotclass@getPixelColor[x, y]@toString[], 
   "=" ~~ d : DigitCharacter .. :> ToExpression@d];

screeninfo = 
  "FullScreenArea" /. 
   Flatten@SystemInformation["Devices", "ScreenInformation"];
screenshot[range : {{x0_, x1_}, {y0_, y1_}} : screeninfo] := 
  GUIScreenShot[range];
```

The name of those functions already explains everything, so no need for extra explanations~ This piece of code has already include all the key features in 按键精灵, a keypress or mouse move simulator used to automate repetitive works, e.g. play HearthStone. But with the ability of Mathematica, I think this piece of code can do much more! :)

Comment: how do I get keypress to emulate "f"